# Backpropagation of simple model

Tags: optimization, partial-derivative, machine-learning, gradient-descent, error-function

I've been attempting to grok how backpropagation works.
I've therefore come up with a super simple model that I wanted to attempt to optimize:

$f_{p}(x) = p x$

For some parameter $p$.

My toy training data look like the following:

$X = \{(1, 1), (2, 2), (3,3)\}$

Therefore the $p$ should obviously end up being $1$.

I'm using a very simple loss function:

$E(X, p) = \frac 12 (\hat{y} - f_p(x))^2$

The change of $p$ per training step $t$ for a learning rate $\alpha$ is defined such that:

$p^{t+1} = p^t - \alpha \frac{\partial E (X, p^t)}{\partial p}$

I'm unsure how I should compute the above, here's my attempt for the first step so far:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
p^{0} &=& -1 \\
p^{1} &=& -1 - \alpha \frac{\partial E(X,p^0)}{\partial p} \\
\frac{\partial E(X,p^0)}{\partial p} &=& 
\frac{\partial}{\partial p} \frac 12 (\hat y -y)^2
\end{eqnarray}$$

But I'm kind of stuck here. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\nabla =&\frac{\partial{E(X, p)}}{\partial p} 
= \frac{\partial ~0.5(\hat y - f_p(x))^2}{\partial p}
= \frac{\partial ~0.5(\hat y - px)^2}{\partial p}
\end{align*}

Here, let's set $q \equiv (\hat y - px)$, so that we can write

$$
\nabla =  \frac{\partial ~0.5(\hat y - px)^2}{\partial p} 
= \frac{\partial 0.5q^2}{\partial p} = 0.5 \frac{\partial{q^2}}{{\partial p}}
$$

We now invoke the chain rule to get:

$$
\nabla = 0.5 \frac{\partial{q^2}}{{\partial p}} = 0.5 \frac{\partial{q^2}}{{\partial q}}  \frac{\partial{q}}{{\partial p}} = 0.5 \cdot 2q \cdot \frac{dq}{dp} = q \frac{dq}{dp}
$$

We now evaluate $\frac{dq}{dp}$ as:

\begin{align*}
\frac{dq}{dp} &= \frac{\partial (\hat y - px)}{\partial p} \\
&=  \frac{\partial \hat y}{\partial p} - \frac{\partial  (px)}{\partial p}\\
&= 0- x\frac{\partial p}{\partial p} \\
&= - x \cdot 1 = -x
\end{align*}

This gives us the full expression:

$$
\nabla = q \frac{dq}{dp} = -qx = (\hat y - px) \cdot (-x)
$$

The important thing to remember is that we assume that $x, \hat y$ are *independent* of the value of $p$ (the parameter), since that's the data.
Therefore:

$$
\frac{\partial x}{\partial p} = 0 \qquad \frac{\partial \hat y}{\partial p} = 0
$$

Also note that in "real world" implementations of automatic differentiation, one *does not compute the derivatives symbolically*. Rather, they're a different set of techniques.

[Here is a good reference on the topic](https://rufflewind.com/2016-12-30/reverse-mode-automatic-differentiation)

Comment: Allright, thanks a lot. It's funny you mention the AD part, I'm actually trying to implement a simple AD program in Haskell with Dual numbers. The article is a great read!

Comment: Glad to be of help! Please tick the answer as approved if this was useful to you :)

Comment: Hmm, could you explain how to do in forward mode? Been spending all day trying to do the computation by hand and still can't figure it out. I think I'm stuck figuring out what the values of x, y and p should be if I try to do it with dual numbers

Comment: Lol never mind, just getting tired. I managed to compute it in forward mode...